# Does Objectify cache the Query.fetchKeys results in memcache?

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have limited seed-data in an entity, for which I want to fetch all keys (unique strings) frequently and whole entity not that frequent.
If I fetch the keys using Query.fetchKeys, does Objectify cache the results in memcache or hit datastore everytime for Query.fetchKeys results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query.fetchKeys() is a method from a very old version of Objectify.

But in answer to your question, all 'queries' (that is, anything besides get-by-key) must pass through to the datastore. Only the datastore knows what satisfies a query.